# How to finish 'Retrieve the GECK for Arroyo' quest?

Tags: fallout-2

> I just got it from Vault 13 by helping deathclaws. I found Hakunin
>  dying and telling about the raid but I don't get xp and quest isn't
>  marked as done. Is there something wrong or do I need to do more
>  stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rescue the village as you can't very well give them the GECK if they aren't there.

Comment: I assume that means "go on, it will be allright", right?

Comment: pretty much, yup

Answer (score 3):

This happens when you either locate the GECK, or if time runs out. You need to rescue your tribe at this point in order to complete the main quest.

Hint 1:

> To rescue your tribe, start by going to San Francisco.

Hint 2:

> San Francisco is located in the bottom left corner of the world map.

Hint 3:

> In San Francisco, you must find a way to get the tanker (large boat) operational.

Hint 4:

> This requires [fuel](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/The_tanker_needs_fuel), a [FOB](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/You_need_to_use_a_FOB_to_access_the_navigation_computer), and a [NavCom part](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/The_navigation_computer_needs_the_NavComp_part_to_work). Once the tanker is operational, you can travel to a place where you can rescue your tribe.

Hint 5:

> You can only go to this place once, and once there you cannot leave until you've finished rescuing your tribe. Prepare yourself before going.

Major Plot spoilers:

> Rescuing your tribe and escaping The Enclave will complete the game and display the final cinematic showing the outcomes of the different locations in Fallout 2 based on what quests you did or did not do.
>  
>  You can keep playing the game as long as you want after completing this.